# Why there are some weird requests to my web hosting

Tags: http, https

[image: Hosted platform logs]

I was doing my plesk hosting logs checking for web and database development. Somehow, I had seen some weird ip trying to communicate to hosting. Wonder what is purpose of these anonymous requests.
Anyone facing this issue before?

Thanks in advance.
P/S: This is still my development stage, should be no one knowing this website address.

Comment: Welcome to SoF. You should ask this question [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/). BTW some innocent requests and some looking for vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Xaqron Thanks for your prompt reply! I will move to there later. Is this common issue for website? can I just ignore them?

Comment: Yes this is common. You can use these logs for build a defense strategy (block IP, harden your website...). Some are just crawlers from search engines so don't block them. If you are sensitive to security use `CloudFlare` or similar services.

Comment: @Xaqron Alright, I will do more research about your opinion. ty

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to restrict access to an IP range of your choosing, from your hosting platform, so that only a limited range of hosts would be able to access your web app.

Comment: GET/HEAD / and robots.txt are okay. The rest are in search of vulnaribilities, like administrating the databaase via the web. One also sees that your 404 page is too fast, a delay would be better (= nastier).